# jqPlot - multiline ticks with angle in x-axis

Tags: text, rotation, jqplot

I have a question about ticks in x-axis. I work with jqPlot 0.9.7

My ticks are multiline, like this: `a <br> b <br> c <br> d`.
I use `renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer` and it works well, so
the ticks show in multiline and 
 works.

Now I need to rotate them 30º. I tried 'angle: -30' but it doesn't
work.

With this config:

```
xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        ticks: ['a <br> b <br> c <br> d' , 'p <br> q <br> r <br> s'],
        tickOptions:{
                angle: -30,
                fontSize: '9px'
        }

}
```

The ticks are shown in one single, rotated, long line. Neither `<br>` nor `\n`
are being interpreted as I need. This is the best approach I have found.

Is there any solution for this? How could I write rotated text ticks?

Any suggestion would be very helpful for me.
Thanks in advance. Best regards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the correct syntax to work you need to include the following scripts along with the defaults jqPlots scripts.

- `jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js`
- `jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js`
- `jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js`

(The above files comes with the jqPlot package).

Then add the following to the plot options list

```
axesDefaults: {
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
},
```

Then your

```
    tickOptions: {
        angle: -30,
    }
```

will be effective.

e.g.

```
....
    series: [{renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: -90,
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        },
        yaxis: {    
            tickOptions: {
                angle: 0,
                fontSize: '10pt'
            }
        }
    },
....
```

Example from jqPlot can be found here:
http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php

Comment: I have this in my script but this is not doing anything :( and yes I do have the scripts

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
```