# how to autoscale xaxis of lineChart in primefaces 3.4

Tags: primefaces, jqplot, overlap, linechart

In my lineChart(primefaces 3.4), xaxis have many dateTimes lables and it overlap, is there any way to prevent overlaping in xaxis?
when in lineChart I use extender attribute(with jqplot function), I can apply autosacle to axis  ***but***  int values labels from 1..n will replaced instead of dateTime lables !.
Here is my sample code:

xhtml Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function setScale() {
          this.cfg.axes ={                
                xaxis:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,                    
                    autoscale : true,
                    }          
        }
</script>
<p:lineChart  value="#{chartBean.chartModel}"  extender="setSacle" xaxisAngle="-30" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `CanvasAxisTickRenderer`

Include `jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js`

and than define

```
xaxis:{
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions: {
       angle: -30
    }
 }
```

Take a look at the jqPlot example : [Rotated Axis Tick Labels | jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php)

And similar question [jqPlot - multiline ticks with angle in x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314178/jqplot-multiline-ticks-with-angle-in-x-axis)

---

Take a loo at the second example on [Axis Labels and Rotated Text](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/axisLabelsRotatedText.html)
It uses `DateAxisRenderer` with `autoscale: true`

```
xaxis: {
      autoscale: true,
      renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
      label: 'Incliment Occurrance',
      labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
      tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
      tickOptions: {
           angle: 15
      }
```

Comment: Because the number of labels is too muchو label rotation will not solve this problem and should decrees them in view **without changing the dateTime value to int value** in xaxis. thank u

Comment: I posted another code snippet . that uses `DateAxisRenderer` with `autoscale` ... take a look at it... its the second example on this page http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/axisLabelsRotatedText.html

Comment: In my code, I used `DateAxisRenderer` with `autoscale: true` but it dosn't work, I don't know if is it bug in  primeFaces?!!! tnx  Daniel :)

Comment: Don't know , but try to add the other settings  , such as  `labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
      tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,`

Answer (score 0):

How about using zoom if you have so many data points:

```
cursor: {
                    show: true,
                    showTooltip: false,
                    zoom: true,
                    constrainZoomTo: 'x'},
```

and

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
```